# How can we install google-chrome-stable on node 12(alpine )image using dockerfile?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, dockerfile

In Node 8 below is the corresponding Docker file

```
FROM node:8-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq libgconf-2-4
# Install latest chrome dev package and fonts to support major charsets (Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, Hebrew, Thai and a few others)
# Note: this installs the necessary libs to make the bundled version of Chromium that Puppeteer
# installs, work.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget --no-install-recommends \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable fonts-ipafont-gothic ttf-freefont git \
      --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && apt-get purge --auto-remove -y curl \
    && rm -rf /src/*.deb
RUN wget -q -O /usr/local/bin/dumb-init https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v1.2.0/dumb-init_1.2.0_amd64 && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
RUN mkdir app && useradd -m app && chown app app
USER app
WORKDIR app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --registry xxxxx --production
ENV CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser \
    CHROME_PATH=/usr/lib/chromium/
COPY test test
COPY src src
# COPY config config
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/dumb-init", "--"]
CMD ["npm", "test"]
```

But the same is not working for Node-12, Is there any changes need to make for the Node 12, its using alpine version and node-8 uses ubuntu

Comment: Can you post the full Dockerfile?

Comment: updated @nischay goyal

Comment: Why can't you use node-12 ubuntu? Is there any restriction that you want to use alpine image?

Comment: yes we are using only node-12:alpine

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using alpine image? If not, then switch back to debian and not much work would be there

Comment: Have a common image buit using alpine in the org so need to use the same

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what's the specific problem you're having?  You can't run `apt-get` on an Alpine-based image (it's just a different package manager), @nischaygoyal's suggestion to use an Ubuntu-based image will address this.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this already built image which has node `v12.16.2` and chrome as well in that.

Image Name `zenika/alpine-chrome:80-with-node`

```
docker run -it zenika/alpine-chrome:80-with-node /bin/sh
/usr/src/app $ node -v
v12.16.2
/usr/src/app $ cat /etc/issue
Welcome to Alpine Linux 3.11
Kernel \r on an \m (\l)
```

> Ref:- https://github.com/Zenika/alpine-chrome

Comment: That wasn't the question, he explicitly asked how do you install chrome not what images have it pre-packaged.